# Centre of Endomorphism algebra and Endomorphism over enveloping algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

This question concerns an equality found on page 219 of Associative Algebras by R. S. Pierce.

> Lemma Let $A$ be an $R$-algebra. Then $Z(A)=End_{A^{e}}(A)$ under the mapping $y\mapsto\lambda_{y}$, where $\lambda_{y}(x)=yx$.

Notation: The enveloping algebra $A^{e}$ is defined by $A^{e}=A^{\ast}\otimes_{R}A$, where $A^{\ast}$ is the opposite algebra to $A$.

In the proof of the Lemma, there is an observation made that $Z(End_{A}(A))=End_{A^{e}}(A)$. I tried proving this observation below but I got stuck halfway.

$\subseteq$: If $\phi\in Z(End_{A}(A))$, then for all $\zeta\in End_{A}(A)$, $\phi\zeta=\zeta\phi$. We need to show that $\phi$ is $A^{e}$-linear. Let $a_{1}\otimes a_{2}\in A^{\ast}\otimes_{R}A$. For any $x\in A$,
\begin{equation*}
\phi(x)(a_{1}\otimes a_{2})=a_{1}\phi(x)a_{2}=a_{1}x(\phi(1))a_{2}=a_{1}xa_{2}
\end{equation*}
and on the other hand
\begin{equation*}
\phi(x(a_{1}\otimes a_{2})=\phi(a_{1}xa_{2})=a_{1}xa_{2}
\end{equation*}
where the last equality follows from that $\phi$ is $A$-linear.

My questions:

1. In the proof of $\subseteq$, I did not use that $\phi$ commutes with every $\zeta\in End_{A}(A)$. Is my proof lacking in any area?
2. For the proof of $\supseteq$, I am unable to connect $\psi$ being $A^{e}$-linear to $\psi$ being in $Z(End_{A}(A))$. How should I approach the proof of $\supseteq$?

Any hints or help is appreciated.